# Null part in deserialize xml to class object

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I must deserialize some xml to object class which I generate from xsd files using xsd.exe. Everything is okey but one part in my object is always null and I don't know why because in xml it have data.

It's the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jdf:root xmlns:jdf="http://www.tmp.com/jdf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <jdf:header>
        <jdf:trace-id>string</jdf:trace-id>
        <jdf:timestamp>string</jdf:timestamp>
        <jdf:command>string</jdf:command>
        <jdf:version>string</jdf:version>
    </jdf:header>
    <even:data xmlns:even="http://tmp.com/zzz/pivot/event">
        <even:event xmlns:com="http://tmp.com/zzz/utils/components">
            <even:eventId>3</even:eventId>
            <even:distributorId>string</even:distributorId>
            <even:distributionNetworkId>string</even:distributionNetworkId>
            <even:typology>string</even:typology>
        </even:event>
    </even:data>
</jdf:root>
```

And this is my class from xsd files:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.tmp.com/jdf")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("root", Namespace = "http://www.tmp.com/jdf", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class JdfRoot
{

    private JdfHeader headerField;

    private object dataField;

    /// <uwagi/>
    public JdfHeader header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }


    /// <uwagi/>
    public object data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dataField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <uwagi/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://mib.bnpp.com/cle/pivot/event")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("data", Namespace = "http://tmp.com/cle/pivot/event", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class T_data
{

    private EventOut eventField;

    /// <uwagi/>
    public EventOut @event
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I left only the most necessary part because full version i very long.

Comment: Which part is always null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the XML namespace for the `data` property correctly by applying [`XmlElementAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    private T_data dataField;

    [XmlElement("data", Namespace = "http://tmp.com/zzz/pivot/event")]
    public T_data data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dataField = value;
        }
    }
```

Also, as Richard Schneider wrote, change the type of `data` to be `T_data`.  If you leave it as an `object` property your `even:data` element tree will be deserialized as an [`XmlNode []`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) array which is probably not what you want.

(The easiest way to find and fix "XML property deserialized as `null`" bugs is to create an example of the class in memory, **serialize** to XML, and compare the output with your input XML.  Usually you'll spot the difference; often it's an incorrect namespace.)

Answer (score 1):

In `JdfRoot`, change `public object data` to `public T_data data`.

Comment: I tried to do and unfortunately it has not changed anything.

Comment: @SteveLillis, this provides an answer. It may not be correct or may not work for the original poster, but it is an answer. Please don't flag this as "Not an answer". If you feel it is a **wrong** answer, downvote, don't flag.